# Add product photo in transactional emails in magento 2

Tags: magento2

In the emails of the Magento 2 orders, all the details of the purchased product arrive, but I would also be interested in placing the image. Someone has implemented it so they can help me, I've tried to find the magento email templates to edit them, but it's all a mess.

I appreciate your help!

[image: mail photo]

Someone has implemented it so they can help me, I've tried to find the magento email templates to edit them, but it's all a mess.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to override below file from "vendor" folder

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

To your theme's design folder

```
app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[TEMPLATE]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

And then fetch product image using below code.

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
$_store = $_order->getStore();

$_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$_baseImageUrl = $_store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';
```

And add below Image tag inside first `<td>` above `<p class="product-name">`

```
<img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('65','65')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
```

you can add Image as separate column as well. But for that you have to override below file as well.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml
```

And need to add extra `<th>` In `<table class="email-items">`

Please try this solution and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: In the event that they are configurable products, how can I show the image of the specific variation of the product that the customer has purchased?

With that I would be complete.

Thank you very much for your help!